# Firebase for Android - not able to set up project

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I am using Android Studio 3.2 and trying to set up a project with firebase auth. I use studeo's helper feature to guide through the steps.

Adding dependency firebase-auth-16.0.xx:15.0.0 - Grade is not able to sync

Remove 15.0.0 gradle syncs but the tool shows that project is not configured for firebase.

How to solve this.

Comment: Could you add the output from the gradle sync that fails? It should help us see what is going wrong.

Comment: can you post your gradle files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked dependencies are added properly? like

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

also add google play services dependency

Comment: I saw in build.graddle file. Is there any other place I should check?

Comment: add this to your build.gradle app module
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

Comment: I have added Google services 4.0.2 as well.

Comment: can I see your build gradle file